# Upper Triangular Matrices of Monotone Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am looking for references to the following problem (I'm actually interested in general $n$, but will use $n=3$ as an example): consider a finite set, for example, $N = \{1,2,3\}$, and the associated power set $P= \{1,2,3,12,13,23,123\}$. For each member $R$ of $P$ let the $7$-dimensional vector $v_R$ be such that $(v_R)_i = 1$ if $R\subset P_i$ and $=0$ otherwise. Now let $M$ be a matrix with $i$th row $v_{P_i}$ (sorry for the notation, what we're just doing is ordering the subsets by their position in $P$). $M$ is clearly upper triangular with $1$s down the diagonal.

My first observation is that these rows span $R^7$; I need to do some work with linear combinations of them (e.g. find out which ones yield non-negative vectors). Is there a name for these "kinds" of matrices, or does any one know of any references to similar structures? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a [set-inclusion matrix](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22set+inclusion+matrix%22). (In the literature the sets are usually restricted by cardinality.) The term [containment matrix](http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.2671) also appears, but often means the symmetric matrix, where $1$ is placed at $ij$ if either of the sets $A_i,A_j$ contains the other.

Other related terms: (i) *containment graph* (especially when directed): see *Graph Classes: A Survey* by Andreas Brandstädt, Van Bang Le, Jeremy P. Spinrad. (ii) *containment order*.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I had done some research and see that in general these matrices represent binary relations or partial orders (IIRC). Thanks for the detailed, comprehensive reply.